# bug with "hostname -i"

Tags: linux, hostname

when i type :

```
hostname -i
```

my return is returning something really strange (for security it is not the real ip)

```
2001:db8:1f89::%et0 2001:db8:1f89::%eth1 2001:db8:1f89::%eth2 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2
```

i have the same configuration on many other machine
and i dont fint why its is not returning the right thing, it should be only the ip set in the /etc/hosts file.

```
192.168.1.1
```

i tried :
hostnamectl
changing the /etc/hosts file
checked the /etc/host.conf
nmcli hostname
/etc/sysconfig/network
/etc/hostname
reboot
nothing point to this

regards,

Comment: The others are auto-generated IPv6 addresses

Comment: Read the documentation, and compare `--ip-address` and `--all-ip-addresses`, specifically how the latter omits IPv6 link-local addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `-i` option display the network addresses of the host name, including the loopback interface and IPv6 link-local addresses.

Using the `-I` option display all network addresses of the host excluding loopback interface and IPv6 link-local addresses.

Sometime reading the man could be enough. Just type `man hostname` :)